# IDLE uses a different python version than python3 on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I develop on Mac OSX (version 11.2.3) with python, using IDLE.

When I run IDLE, it uses python version 3.8.1, which has been installed in `/usr/local/bin`. For some reason I cannot run python3.8 via the command line from `/usr/local/bin` - it just returns 'file not found' or 'command not found'. I've tried running `python3.8` or `./python3.8` or `/usr/local/bin/python3.8` and they all come up with errors, even though I can see the file in there.

When I use python via the command line, it uses python version 3.8.2 which has been installed in `usr/bin`. There's python2.7 in there as well, and I can run python2.7 by typing 'python2.7' just fine. the command `python` runs python2.7 and the command `python3` runs python 3.8.2.

Running python jobs via the crontab causes errors with scripts I have written using IDLE. These seem mainly to do with libraries. IDLE looks for libraries in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` while python3 looks for them in `/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages`. When I install a package via `pip3` it installs them in `/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages` and then I have to move them to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` to get them to work in IDLE.

I start IDLE as idle3 from `/usr/bin` and it uses python3.8.1.

How do I get IDLE to use `python3.8.2` so it uses the same python as the 'python3' command?

Comment: We can't tell from the information you posted where Python is actually installed. How do you run IDLE? What's in `/usr/local/bin/python*`?

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed the former, as you are specifically asking about 3.8.

Comment: /usr/local/bin has python3.8. /usr/bin has python, python 2.7, python2 and python3. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install these different Python versions? Which version does `/usr/local/bin/python3` run? What about `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`? Is it a symlink to a binary which no longer exists?

Comment: It seems that the idle or idle3 command runs a version of python3.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin. This is version 3.8.1. I need to know how to get the idle command to run the version of python in /usr/local/bin, which is version 3.8.2. Hope you can help.

Comment: In that case, doesn't Serge's answer do exactly that? Probably comment on it to clarify how it's not working if not.

Comment: No Serge's solutiuon does nor work. The response I get is 'no module called idlelib'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact IDLE is no more than a Python module from the standard library. So if you have a command that starts a specific Python version (let us call it `python3.x`) then you can start an IDLE using that version with:

```
python3.x -m idlelib
```

Comment: The OP seems to ask about the opposite problem, though; they know how to run IDLE, but not how to run the corresponding Python version.

Comment: @tripleee: If I understand correctly, they want IDLE to use the 3.8.2 version that they can start with `python3`. I know that English is not my first language but that is what I understand even after a second reading (much more in fact...): *How do I get IDLE to use python3.8.2 so it uses the same python as the 'python3' command?*

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes that is correct, thank you :)

Comment: @SergeBallesta No, I was acknowledging that your understanding of the question was correct. Your solution does not work.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3 -m idlelib` does not work because the OS-installed Python3 (3.8.1) does not include IDLE; but this says to try `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m idlelib` or simply `python3 -m idlelib`; but we are still in the dark as to which version is installed exactly where and exactly how, so this is necessarily speculative.

Comment: Python3.8.2 is intalled in /usr/bin/. Python 3.8.1 is installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/. As you say, there is no idlelib for 3.8.2. The only IDLE runs 3.8.1. This is the only version of IDLE on my Mac.

Comment: With your suggestions, I have solved my issue. I copied idlelib so that python3.8.2 could use it, then used Serge's command to start it. I now have a version of IDLE that runs 3.8.2. Many thanks, Peter.